# What's going on with these Snow in Summer plants?

Tags: diagnosis, flowers, perennials

I planted about a dozen Snow in Summer flowers about 2 months ago and most of them are turning brown in the center. I don't think this is a water issue, but perhaps... the ground doesn't drain very well. Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your pictures I am going to say too little sun and too much water.  Have these plants bloomed at all this year? Doesn't look like they have.  I'd move these plants to a sunnier location and allow the soil to dry out in-between waterings.  Best place for this plant is on top of a rock wall, rockery.  In case you have a one lying around somewhere? Grin...

Once Cerastium tomentosum, Snow in Summer, blooms (should be early summer), cut off all the flowers, shear this plant.  Needs great drainage, can deal with partial shade, a bit of a short-lived ground-cover, has to be sheared to keep dense. Use Osmocote 14-14-14, extended release fertilizer twice during the growth season.

Please let me know if my assumptions were correct, I'll correct the best I am able!

Comment: I think they are getting too much water. The problem is the soil is pretty damp because of bad drainage. What if I add rocks to this bed?

Answer (score 2):

More or less in agreement with previous answer, but for one thing. As said, this appearance is normal for this plant if you don't shear it back to 2 inches after its flowered, I'm afraid, and particularly if grown in less than full sun in dampish soil. Here's the disagreement - it doesn't appreciate being fed very much, grows much better in poor soil, so I wouldn't feed it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely scrape out all the bark and use a good few inches of gravel under and around instead as your plant is rotting where it's wet. A good haircut and I'd hope that would do the trick. Can't beat this gorgeous plant!